# JavaScript separators and closures

Tags: javascript, loops, closures

I need some help understanding closures in JavaScript. I need to make a function (function1) that inserts the specified separator between the array elements, or a comma if a separator is not given. I've tried it like this, but it`s not working.

```
function function1(separator)
{
    return function(elements)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
        return (`${elements}`+ separator);
    };
}


var ex1 = function1("/");
ex1("One"); 
ex1("Two"); 


var ex2 = function1("*");
ex2("One"); 
ex2("Two"); 


var ex3 = function1();
ex3("One");
ex3("Two");


console.log("ex1 is" + ex1() );
console.log("ex2 is " + ex2() );
console.log("ex3 is " + ex3() );
```

The output should be

```
ex1 is One/Two
ex2 is One*Two
ex3 is One,Two
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just about there with your function. The main aspect that's missing is the use of a closure to hold the elements.

If your outer function defines an array, that array will be accessible to the inner function. That's the closure. Then the returned function will take a single element and push it into the components array.

```
function function1(separator){
    let components = []
    return function(element){
        // this function, even after returned, will have access to components
        // through a closure so you can push into components
        // and return something like components.join(separator)
     }
}
```

You should probably check with an element so you don't push empty values.

**Edit—more on closures**
Here's the basic problem: suppose you have function that returns a function like this:

```js
function makelist(seperator){
   return function(element){
      let components = []
      components.push(element)
      return components
   }
 }
 
// now use it
// it returns a function
let myFun = makelist(",")

// but every time you run it, it makes a new components
console.log(myFun("a"))  // ["a"]
console.log(myFun("b"))  // ["b"]
// etc.
```

So that's not good because you want to push into the *same* array every time you call the function. You *could* solve this problem by making a global variable the functions access:

```js
var GloablComponents = []

function makelist(seperator){
   return function(element){
      GloablComponents.push(element)
      return GloablComponents
   }
 }
 
// now use it
// it returns a function
let myFun = makelist(",")

// Now every time you use it, it pushes to the same array:
console.log(myFun("a"))  // ["a"]
console.log(myFun("b"))  // ["a", "b"]
// etc.

// But there's a problem:
// You want to make independent functions.
// If you make another, it pushes to myFun list as well:

let newFun = makelist(",")
console.log(newFun("C"))  // ["a", "b", "C"] // not what you want
```

So that's no good, and it's also not a great habit to depend on global variables because they're hard to keep track of.

**Closures**
Every function creates its own scope, so if you create a function with a variable and then create another function inside it, that inner function will see the variable because it has access to the outer function's scope:

```js
function makelist(seperator){
       let aLocalComponent = []         // <------ this out scope
       return function(element){        //          |
          aLocalComponent.push(element) // <-- THIS is referencing
          return aLocalComponent
       }
     }
     
// now use it
// it returns a function
let myFun = makelist(",")

// Now every time you use it, it pushes to the same array
// but it's not a global array, it's the array from
// makelist's scope. That's a closure
console.log(myFun("a"))  // ["a"]
console.log(myFun("b"))  // ["a", "b"]

// Now when make a new function, makelist makes another independent 
// scope. And the new function returned has access to it and its aLocalComponent

let mySecondFun = makelist(",")
console.log(mySecondFun("Z"))  // ["z"]

//At the sametime the old function still accesses the old localcomponentarray:
console.log(myFun("c"))     // only a, b, c
```

You can use the same idea to make sure the returned functions have the same separator.

Comment: can you please give me more details about that closure? This is exactly where I've got stuck. There are some closure examples online, but i don't really find them relevant. Some help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @Ale - if you are familiar with object oriented programming you can think of closures as very lightweight classes that can only have one method (the function itself) and implemented using a function-like interface instead of a struct-like interface

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sepfnc(spchar){
    this.spchar = spchar;

    this.join = (a,b)=>{
        return a + this.spchar + b
     }

}


var t = new sepfnc("*");


var c =   t.join("a","b")

alert(c)
```

better way is pass your values as array like

```
var inputArr = ["a","b"]

functionname("*" , inputArr )
```

and then work on joining them

if you want to use something like that you must store your **char** value as object in your function and use `new` keyword

like

```
function sepfnc(spchar){
    this.spchar = spchar;

    this.join = (a,b)=>{
        return a + this.spchar + b
     }

}


var t = new sepfnc("*");


var c =   t.join("a","b")
```

Comment: Thank you @hossein , but the problem is that i am not allowed to work with the elements themselves. I can only change function1 and it is supposed to work with any array, which means that they may not always contain only the same 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding... you have a series of words designated elements. you wish to create a string with a set divider between them. The array will need to have a scope of the function, so will either need to be declared outside of the function declaration or used as an argument. I have some confusion as to whether or not it is required that the array be passed via a second function. if not there is an example in:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments :

```
function myConcat(separator) {
     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
     return args.join(separator);
}
```

That takes in a series of arguments and separates them with a designated separator. it is quite an elegant solution, and seems to accomplish what you are looking to do. Otherwise you will need to declare a global variable and use it to concat the array as each time you call the function will need to access it. You can pass it as an argument, but that would mean that the function above would be sufficient.